# Copies contents from one file to another

Tags: c, command, cp

Write a program that copies the contents from one file to another in c on linux platform(ubuntu) OR create a program which make copies of files in ubuntu

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment. If that's the case, we frown on those here. We'll help with specific questions, but we aren't going to do it for you. If it's not, please be a little more specific as to your question...not just "write this for me please."

Comment: OK - I've done that...now what?  Where are you having problems with your attempt?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into using redirection and pipes like you would with a Shell? this example below was from a shell I wrote, this is specifically the redirect function. (>>)
so you could do file1 >> file2 and it would copy the contents of one file to another.
the

```
open(file[0], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666); and while ((count = read(0, &c, 1)) > 0)
          write(fd, &c, 1)
```

; //Write to file are the important parts

```
void redirect_cmd(char** cmd, char** file) {
  int fds[2]; // file descriptors
  int count;  // used for reading from stdout
  int fd;     // single file descriptor
  char c;     // used for writing and reading a character at a time
  pid_t pid;  // will hold process ID; used with fork()

  pipe(fds);


  if (fork() == 0) {
    fd = open(file[0], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    dup2(fds[0], 0);
    close(fds[1]);

    // Read from stdout
    while ((count = read(0, &c, 1)) > 0)
      write(fd, &c, 1); //Write to file

    exit(0);

  //Child1
  } else if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {
    dup2(fds[1], 1);

    //Close STDIN
    close(fds[0]);

    //Output contents
    execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
    perror("execvp failed");

  //Parent
  } else {
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    close(fds[0]);
    close(fds[1]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The General IDEA

- Open one file using [fopen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fopen/)
- Open a Second File using fopen
- Read from the first file using [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/)
- Write to the Second File use [fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/)
- You can substitute [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/) for fread and, [fprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fprintf/) for fwrite if you need to write formated data.

Comment: For file copying, you would not substitute scanf() and printf(), because the data is not formatted.

Comment: Depends on what the specifics of the assignment are but thats why I put them as substitutes

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what programming language must be used. So, I'll assume you're using bash. Write a script that uses the `cp` command and your assignment is solved.

Comment: "Write a program that copies the contents from one file to another **in c**...". The "question" (if you want to call it that) is also tagged with C.

Comment: My mistake. I'll be more careful next time. And the "C" tag is pretty narrow ;-)

Comment: I'll concede that one. It's a sneaky little bugger.